# Validate external token asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a mobile app in Xamarin Forms, which should be able to connect to an ASP.NET core web service (API). I also want the information on the web service to be secured by limiting it to Microsoft account signed-in users. The idea I had was to send the user's credentials and retrieve back the security token from the Microsoft graph within the mobile app. Afterwards, the user would send that same bearer token to the web service, which checks its validity, and grants the requested information only if the validation is successful.

I am new to web development, so first of all, I want to ask if I am using a good approach for my project (if not, what do you recommend?).

If it is, how should I set up the ConfigureServices function in my Startup class? When I include the [Authorize] tag in the controllers, the service crashes, telling me I should define an authentication scheme. I don't need authentication, only authorization (since authentication is done from the mobile app), Since these two are handled independently in asp.net core, I added a dummy jwt authentication scheme as a placeholder. However, when I send an http request with the security token from my mobile app, it gives me a 401 unauthorized error, telling me I'm sending an "invalid token" (this token works fine when connecting to the Microsoft graph).

I've searched in countless documentations, but all of them only consider scenarios in which the authentication is done within the web service, and not externally, like me.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This has a very nice example about how you can implement your JWT and integrate with your end client application.
https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

I personally learned to implement JWT and my own mobile application using the link above. I hope it helps you as well. At least to understand how it works !

Comment: This is a good question, I am working with a similar setup, trying to retrieve Google OAuth2 / Oidc tokens and validate them in Asp.net core 2. Core 2 is good to recognize the token and create  a IClaimsPrincipal with nice claims and the token itself is recognized with jwt.io website. However, I cant validate the authenticity of the token in the form of performing a Jwt bearer token validation. It is the mobile app that will first redirect to Google and grab the token and sendt it to asp.net core 2 solution.